# Repeating code in html.erb page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this following piece of code which gets repeated multiple times in my html.erb page.

```
   <% object_info.attributes.each do |attr_name, attr_value| %>
            <span class="attribute_title"><%= attr_name %>:</span>
            <span class="attribute_value"><%= attr_value %> </span>
            <br/>
    <% end %>
```

I would like to put it in a method so that I just need to call the method when I need it.

I tried putting it in a helper page as a method and call it on my html page:

```
  def display_obj_attributes(active_record_obj)

    data =    "<% #{active_record_obj}.attributes.each do |attr_name, attr_value| %>
            <span class='attribute_title'><%= attr_name %>:</span>
            <span class='attribute_value'><%= attr_value %> </span>
            <br/>
          <% end %>"


    return data.html_safe


  end
```

But it does not seem to work.

Any suggestion?

Comment: use a partial, cleaner

Comment: oh yes...can't believe i missed that

Comment: yeah, a partial is what you want... you don't want to generate html in a ruby method when you can simply use a partial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one solution.

```
def display_obj_attributes(active_record_obj)
  data = ''
  active_record_obj.attributes.each do |attr_name, attr_value|
    data += content_tag(:span, "#{attr_name}:", :class => 'attribute_title')
    data += content_tag(:span, attr_value, :class => 'attribute_value')
    data += '<br/>'
  end
end

<%= display_obj_attributes(toto) %>
```

A prettier is to use partials... A partial use to describe HTML ; a helper function use to help HTML rendering.

```
<%= render :partial => 'obj_attributes', :locals => { :active_record_obj => toto } %>
```

Answer (score 2):

Put it an a partial, _my_partial.js:

```
<% object_info.attributes.each do |attr_name, attr_value| %>
  <span class="attribute_title"><%= attr_name %>:</span>
  <span class="attribute_value"><%= attr_value %> </span>
  <br/>
<% end %>
```

Then in your view:

```
<%= render 'my_partial', object_info: object_info %>
```